# Незнакомый синтаксис в WPF проекте

Tags: c#, wpf

До сего момента не сильно сталкивался с WCF.
Сегодня, разбирая чужой код, наткнулся на объявление свойства и присвоение ему пустого делегата:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

Вопрос: зачем так? И на что влияет если нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например в неком методе мы вызываем делегат

```
PropertyChanged.Invoke(...)
```

дык вот, если `=delegate { };` не будет, то словим исключение.

Дабы избежать этого есть 3 способа:

1. `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };`
2. `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...);`
3. `if (PropertyChanged!=null) PropertyChanged.Invoke(...);`